# rails: has_many with 2 relations fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Hi I have a relation between 2 models. The models are "Category" and "Page". 
I have now the use case that I need 2 Pages/Category. How can I write this? 
The fields in Category are "page_id" and "page_en_id".

I'm not sure which is the best solution for this, I only know the belongs_to and has_many solution with foreign key option which makes here no sense for me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, what you're looking for, but it looks like that:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
  has_many :en_categories, :foreign_key => 'page_en_id', :class_name => 'Category'
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :page
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is my solution now, thanks guys:

Page

```
has_one :category
has_one :category_en, :foreign_key => 'page_en_id', :class_name => 'Page'
```

Category

```
belongs_to :page
belongs_to :page_en, :class_name => "Page"
```